# Laravel, Guzzlehttp, cURL error 56: Recv failure

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Hi there i have a Laravel running into my docker(nginx, php, mysql)
and other Laravel outside of this container just with php artisan serve --port=9000

well im trying to getting these two apps exchanging information, so im using Guzzle to do so.
the problem is, at my docker laravel app which guzzle is installed im trying to http:localhost:8090/test , the route sends me to controller:

```
public function exchange()
{
    $client = new Client();

    $request = $client->post( 'http://localhost:9000/exchange', [
        'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']
    ]);

    return $request;
}
```

what am i supposed to receive, the other app at port 9000:

```
public function index()
{
    $someNumber = 322441000;

    return $someNumber;
}
```

but instead a receive an error:
 `GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException
cURL error 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

so went to: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
@56 and :

```
CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56)
Failure with receiving network data.
```

which didnt helped much.
well if someone know how to fix, whelp!

Comment: why not try to use response with json header in your index(){}
Also make your $someNumber[] = blahblahblah;
return response()->json($someNumner);

Comment: This error is with your network configuration, not your Laravel or Guzzle use. The issue is that `localhost:9000` is not accessible from within your docker container. Docker isn't, as far as I know, designed to allow a container to access the host. You'd need to set up 2 containers and link them.

Comment: Neat. i tested two laravel apps out of docker and they work fine.
gonna link now my docker apps and might work.
Thank you sam :)